# MvxViewModels (childeren) loaded by MvxTabActivity do not raise Start() and can't use same View?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there any solution that MvxViewModels that are loaded from MvxTabActivity do not raise Start() and can't use the same View?

This happens when loading Child ViewModels like:

```
tabSpecs.SetContent(this.CreateIntentFor(MyViewModel.Child1));
```

then

```
public override void Start()
```

Doesn't get raised.

And when I use a single type of child ViewModel for multiple childeren the tab activity seems to cache the first Tab view and shows it on every tab.

Anyone any solution how to use the same View for multiple tabs and to use the Start Method that I normaly use for Async loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the solution, possibly there isn't any.

Fragments in Android do support using the same Views, so use them as content placeholder for every tab. (especially when you use the same Views in multiple tabs)